# Very specific questions (grammatical errors suspected)

Tags: word-usage, dative

I just finished reading the following article: https://www.tagesschau.de/ausland/asien/israel-ausreisen-100.html

Is it normal for them to say:

"Um deutsche Bürgerinnen und Bürger aus Israel herauszubringen, organisierte die Lufthansa insgesamt acht Sonderflüge. Auch die Bundeswehr startete **zu** vier Flügen, mit denen Material nach Israel gebracht wurde und auf dem Rückweg Deutsche ausgeflogen wurden. Mithilfe der Bundeswehr konnten etwa 220 Menschen das Land verlassen. Am Sonntag startete aus Akaba im benachbarten Jordanien ein Sonderflug. Zudem nutzten zahlreiche Deutsche kommerzielle Flugverbindungen, um aus Israel auszureisen."

I.e. is the zu really necessary?

Also, why is the plural dative -n ending not applied to the word Familienangehörige?

"Die USA wollen die Ausreise auch über den Seeweg ermöglichen. Dafür soll eine Fähre von Haifa nach Zypern aufbrechen. Die Mitreise soll laut US-Botschaft in Israel ausschließlich US-Bürgerinnen und -bürgern und deren unmittelbaren **Familienangehörige**, also Ehepartnern oder Kindern, vorbehalten sein. Zudem kündigte die US-Regierung Charterflüge aus Israel an."

After all, it is present in Bürgerinnen, -bürgern, deren, unmittelbaren, Ehepartnern & Kindern.

Comment: These are two very different questions and should therefore be asked separately.

Comment: but one of them is just a tiny question...

Answer (score 3):

1. "zu etwas starten" is a possible expression for someone undertaking a flight -- though I can't explain why this expression exists. See also https://www.dwds.de/wb/starten#d-1-1-3 "zu einer Reise, Expedition, ... starten". The meaning is then that people themselves are moving, so here: Bundeswehr staff is setting out for Israel. Without the "zu" you would get a transitive construction "Flüge starten", which is possible but has a causative meaning.
2. "Familienangehörige" without -n is obviously a typo. It is in parallel with "Bürgern" which has one.

Answer (score 0):

The *zu* is necessary as part of an [infinitive group](https://de-m-wikipedia-org.translate.goog/wiki/Infinitivgruppe?_x_tr_sl=de&_x_tr_tl=en&_x_tr_hl=de&_x_tr_pto=wapp), a form of sub-clause explaining what exactly the flights are offered for. The verb *ausreisen* is separable (into prefix *aus* and verb *reisen*); separable verbs are contracted into one orthographic word *auszureisen* for this infinitive group.

The missing plural dative -n ending is an error.

Comment: The first question was about an earlier "zu" that is marked in bold typeface, not about "auszureisen".